# Pandas iterate over multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm at a loss, any help is appreciated.

I'm getting back this multiindex dataframe from pandas:
[image]

I want to:

1. Loop over all the orange outlined column name and **get** the column name as well
2. Gain access to each green outlined row based on the column name in orange

I've read a lot of documentation and tried numerous things to no avail

Something like:

```
for ticker in df.columns:
    ticker.iloc[0:5]
```

(I know the above code isn't correct, but that's the jist of what I want to do)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `unstack` then each column is the green value

```
df.loc['2020-10-07'].unstack()
```